# create clubhouse avatar with flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm unable to create clubhose avatar in flutter because the image widget background is dynamic or video , so i'm try to use clubhose avatar as blue print and then clipping with the new dynamic image from api .

here is my code :

```dart
Container(
            height: height,
            width: width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.elliptical(width / 3 * 1.4, width / 3 * 1.6),
                ),
                // color: mainColor,
                image: decorationImage ??
                    DecorationImage(image: AssetImage(unknown_person))),
            child: child ?? SizedBox(),
          );
```

this was i wanted without black border .

[image]
[image]

this what i got :

[image]

Comment: you want it to be rounded?

Comment: @MunsifAli yes , see the updated white image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I should convert the figma SVG avatar shape with this website https://www.flutterclutter.dev/tools/svg-to-flutter-path-converter

then I have to use the ImageClipper class to clip the user profile image to the path as follows :

```
    class ImageClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.02, size.height * 0.3);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.05, size.height * 0.16, size.width * 0.16,
        size.height * 0.05, size.width * 0.3, size.height * 0.02);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.43, -0.01, size.width * 0.57, -0.01,
        size.width * 0.7, size.height * 0.02);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.84, size.height * 0.05, size.width * 0.95,
        size.height * 0.16, size.width * 0.98, size.height * 0.3);
    path.cubicTo(size.width, size.height * 0.43, size.width, size.height * 0.57,
        size.width * 0.98, size.height * 0.7);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.95, size.height * 0.84, size.width * 0.84,
        size.height * 0.95, size.width * 0.7, size.height * 0.98);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.57, size.height, size.width * 0.43, size.height,
        size.width * 0.3, size.height * 0.98);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.16, size.height * 0.95, size.width * 0.05,
        size.height * 0.84, size.width * 0.02, size.height * 0.7);
    path.cubicTo(-0.01, size.height * 0.57, -0.01, size.height * 0.43,
        size.width * 0.02, size.height * 0.3);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.02, size.height * 0.3, size.width * 0.02,
        size.height * 0.3, size.width * 0.02, size.height * 0.3);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

and here is my final widget :

```
RepaintBoundary(
  key: GlobalKey(),
  child: ClipPath(
    clipper: ImageClipper(),
    child: CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: imagePath!,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            width: double.infinity,
            placeholder: (context, url) =>
                Image.asset(unknown_person),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                Image.asset(unknown_person),
          )
      
  ))
```

the SVG image for reference :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-iPnvh8_JDoCrnwSfdB7P92qdQpHmVRr/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

To round corners, there's a special Widget for that - [`ClipRRect`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html):

> A widget that clips its child using a rounded rectangle.

[image]

To make an elliptical shape, you specify the [`Radius.elliptical`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Radius/Radius.elliptical.html) constructor (as you have already done):

```dart
ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
    Radius.elliptical(100, 100), // horizontal, vertical
),
     child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'))
```

Comment: thank you for your response , i was tested it before but the right and left side not curved as clubhouse avatar , all four rounds must be curved but not as circle see: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QUr43DdO-CoenyL8P-0rxzf40BQE-FVC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @HeshamELnemr I see. Maybe play around with the radius? (it's currently at `100` by `100`)

Comment: @MwbdelG , yes i tested it with many values , but didn't get what i'm looking for , still got upper and bottom curved but right and left side shows as line not curved .

Answer (score 0):

Use Container with `clipBehaviour` property and give radius to every corner according to your need like this

```dart
Container(
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
// give radius to each corner different
      color: Colors.black,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
        topRight: Radius.circular(20),
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(50),
      ),
    ),
    child: Image.asset(
      'assets/images/stripe.png',
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
    ),
  )
```

this what you will got

[image]

Comment: thanks , but i'm looking for better results to be same as my attached photo above , and your solution works for me up to 90% , what is there is other solution so i can blueprint the original  photo and clip the profile image on it ?